# Access select box value from server aspnet

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, server-side

I am trying to get the value of a client side select box in the server side of an `aspx`.
For example, In a `button_click`, I would like to make a connection to a database depending on the value of a select box of client side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `WebMethod` .
This is the example of [Calling an ASP.NET C# Method (Web Method) Using JavaScript](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/calling-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-javascript/) .
Get your select box value in `javascript` , pass this value as parameter to server side `WebMethod` and make a connection to a database depending on this value !